# Instalar paquetes en R a partir de archivos .tar.gz (Ubuntu)

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, packages

A la hora de instalar paquetes en R Studio me suele dar error porque no los encuentra. Hay veces que lo he podido solucionar instalando el pauqte en Ubuntu dsde la terminal (con apt) pero otras veces no. Estoy intentando instalar el paquete "sf" y me falla el paquete "classInt". Creia que lo había instalado con apt :

`sudo apt-get install r-cran-classint`

Pero en R studio me sigue dando mensaje de error:

`Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘classInt’ had non-zero exit status`

He descargado el archivo .tar.gz de la página de CRAN (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/classInt/index.html)

e instalarlo desde ahí, y me sigue dando el mismo error.¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Intenta instalar  `classInt`, y agrega la salida completa del error a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

intenta instalando

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('paquete', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

Comment: Podrías editar tu respuesta y agregar <x> por favor? Así aumentarás su calidad, será mejor recibida y tanto el autor de la pregunta como quienes vean tu respuesta más adelante podrían aprender algo nuevo.

Comment: ¿Podrias agregar porque eso responde a la pregunta?  Las respuestas con solo código sin ningún tipo de explicación son consideradas de baja calidad.